# react-transition-group lifecycle method componentWillLeave not being called

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to get `componentWillLeave` to get called and I'm having no luck.  `componentWillAppear` gets called, but I'm unable to get the former to call. Most responses I've seen call for making sure the callbacks are being called, which I am doing. I'm also using React router if that makes a difference. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { TweenMax } from 'gsap';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import { Animated } from '../../components/common/Animated';
import NavButton from '../../components/navButton/NavButton';

import './Team.scss';

class Team extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.el = this.refs.container;
  }

  componentWillAppear(callback) {
    TweenMax.set(this.el, { x: '100%' });
    TweenMax.to(this.el, 1, { x: '0%' });
    callback();
  }

  componentWillLeave(callback) {
    TweenMax.to(this.el, 1, { x: '-100%', onComplete: callback });
  }

  render() {
    const { match } = this.props;
    return (
      <div ref="container" className="teamContainer">
        <NavButton
          title={'To Interactive'}
          route={`/${match.params.monster}/interactive`}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Team.propTypes = {
  match: PropTypes.shape({
    pathname: PropTypes.shape({
      monster: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    }),
  }),
};

Team.defaultProps = {
  match: {
    pathname: {
      monster: -1,
    },
  },
};

export default Animated(Team);
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this with react router, but with a similar router approach. I got it to work using TransitionGroup v1.x and made sure my active child component was

1. a react element
2. had it's own unique key

https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group/tree/v1-stable

> Note:
>
> When using CSSTransitionGroup, there's no way for your components to be notified when a transition has ended or to perform any more complex logic around animation. If you want more fine-grained control, you can use the lower-level TransitionGroup API which provides the hooks you need to do custom transitions.